# Where's this vineyard in front of a river and moutains, in Okanagan Valley BC?

Tags: identify-this, british-columbia

Where exactly must I stand to see this panorama? This picture's the [banner](https://www.lonelyplanet.com/canada/british-columbia/okanagan-valley).

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The picture is from West Kelowna, BC. You can find images taken from a similar angle on [Google Street View](https://www.google.de/maps/@49.84097,-119.5729299,3a,30.8y,163.45h,85.3t/data=!3m7!1e1!3m5!1sae5NbIsKzaf-5eEC8j7Oyw!2e0!6s%2F%2Fgeo2.ggpht.com%2Fcbk%3Fpanoid%3Dae5NbIsKzaf-5eEC8j7Oyw%26output%3Dthumbnail%26cb_client%3Dmaps_sv.tactile.gps%26thumb%3D2%26w%3D203%26h%3D100%26yaw%3D97.34605%26pitch%3D0%26thumbfov%3D100!7i13312!8i6656). The Lonely Planet photographer was probably standing a bit down the gravel road leading down to the water.

Following the shore of Lake Okanagan, this was the only peninsula somehow matching the shape of the peninsula in the image.